# a:hover color change not working properly

Tags: css

I have a site with a bunch of anchor elements, and I'm trying to make them have a black background with white text on hover. Each anchor tag is wrapped in li. Funny thing is, only some anchor elements change their style on hover, and some don't. For example, the first three menu items in the menu change the text color, but the rest doesn't change the color. The background color works for every item. This is my code:

```
a, a:visited {
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

a:hover,
a:hover span{
color:white !important;
background:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

<div id="navblock">
  <ul class="nav fullwidthnav">
     <li> <a href="/collections/newarrivals">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/house">HOUSE LABELS</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/knits">KNITS</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/tops">TOPS</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/dresses">DRESSES</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/bottoms">BOTTOMS</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/jackets-coats">OUTERWEAR</a></li>
     <li><a href="/collections/shoes">SHOES</a></li>
 </ul>
  <div class="clearit"></div>
</div><!-- #navblock -->
```

Comment: @Valamas-AUS: Added some html.

Comment: [The code you provided works](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/BHfwk/) It has to be something else

Comment: @ZachSaucier:Do you have any idea what it could be...?

Comment: @JaeeunLee No, given there is nothing for me to go off of with the code you've given

Answer (score 0):

`a:visited` is your culprit.

It is not being overridden by `a:hover` because it is both visited and hover so would need to be `a:visited:hover`  which will work in modern browsers but possibly not IE compatible.

A question to ask may be do you really need a "visited" style? Is that something users really need?

Comment: `a:visited:hover` is not needed if you place `a:hover` **after** `a:visited` and the OP also did like that.

Answer (score 0):

I used -webkit-text-fill-color instead of just color, and now it works.